# How to find the script (screenplay) of old silent movies?

Tags: silent-movie

I'm trying to find the script of D. W. Griffith's `Birth of a Nation`, and it seems that nobody has it on the internet.

Is there a movie database out there from which I can get the text of old movies (silent movies)?

Usually the technique is to show some text between scenes, but I need to find texts (analytical purposes) and I can't watch all of them, trying to extract the screenplay out of the movie.

Answer (score 5):

To answer the first part of your question, there are a couple of decent resources for old movie scripts, [Simply Scripts](http://www.simplyscripts.com/genre/silent-movie-scripts.html) being a good one.

As for Birth of a Nation, it was my understanding that Griffith did not commit a script *Per Se* to paper, but rather had the whole film in his head at the time of shooting. The interstitial cards were added in retrospect to convey emotional moments, inner thoughts and extra exposition.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It was helpful. But I didn't know that Griffith had such a style of movie production. I guess there should be a place on the net, where I can get the script of his movies, even if somebody has already collected it informally. +1.

Comment: You also asked about "texts" in silent films, which I guess you meen the titles (sometimes called intertitles, but never that during the silent era). The website http://intertitleorama.webs.com/ has listings of all of the titles on many silent films that still survive.